# Scan a rails app's code for SQL injection vulnerabilities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

How can I scan a rails app's code for patterns that may be SQL injection points?

For example, it should find any of the patterns listed here: https://rails-sqli.org/

As a specific example, if this was in the app's code, a scanner should find it and flag it as an SQL injection point.

```rb
User.find_by params[:id]
```

#### What I've tried

I tried brakeman (`brakeman -f html -o report.html`) to check for all of these:

```
BasicAuth, BasicAuthTimingAttack, CSRFTokenForgeryCVE, ContentTag, CookieSerialization, CreateWith, CrossSiteScripting, DefaultRoutes, Deserialize, DetailedExceptions, DigestDoS, DynamicFinders, EscapeFunction, Evaluation, Execute, FileAccess, FileDisclosure, FilterSkipping, ForgerySetting, HeaderDoS, I18nXSS, JRubyXML, JSONEncoding, JSONEntityEscape, JSONParsing, LinkTo, LinkToHref, MailTo, MassAssignment, MimeTypeDoS, ModelAttrAccessible, ModelAttributes, ModelSerialize, NestedAttributes, NestedAttributesBypass, NumberToCurrency, PageCachingCVE, PermitAttributes, QuoteTableName, Redirect, RegexDoS, Render, RenderDoS, RenderInline, ResponseSplitting, RouteDoS, SQL, SQLCVEs, SSLVerify, SafeBufferManipulation, SanitizeMethods, SelectTag, SelectVulnerability, Send, SendFile, SessionManipulation, SessionSettings, SimpleFormat, SingleQuotes, SkipBeforeFilter, SprocketsPathTraversal, StripTags, SymbolDoSCVE, TemplateInjection, TranslateBug, UnsafeReflection, ValidationRegex, WithoutProtection, XMLDoS, YAMLParsing
```

#### Question

Is there a way to quickly and easily scan some code for potential SQL injection vulnerabilities?

Comment: Did you mean `User.find_by("name = #{user_params[:name]}")` or `User.find_by(name: user_params[:name])` because the former is naturally injectable but the latter is not. Right now `User.find_by(name = user_params[:name])` is technically injectable but more just awful code and more likely to result in malformed queries than anything else.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for spotting that, I copied the wrong thing, I updated the question with the correct vulnerability from the sqli website

Comment: While "technically" injectable given the fact that modern rails will append `order` and `limit` statements to that statement chances are you will just end up with a SQL error.